# Decode symbols in string

Tags: php, encoding

`echo $name` gives me `Mount Kimbie &mdash; Carbonated`.

How do I get `Mount Kimbie — Carbonated`?

&mdash, quotes and other stuff should be decoded into regular symbols.

I've tried both `htmlspecialchars_decode($name)` and `html_entity_decode($name)`, they don't work.

Comment: $name = html_entity_decode($name);

Comment: `var_dump(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5));` Try this and look if `mdash` is inside.

Comment: `html_entity_decode($name)` seems to be working fine http://ideone.com/Wkjvkm

Comment: `html_entity_decode` is encode depended. See answer of @mario

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably lack the charset parameter:

```
html_entity_decode($name, 0, "UTF-8");
```

Depending on PHP version, Latin-1 was assumed, which does not harbor `mdash`.

Comment: Ah, I always forget about this. Used to UTF-8 being the default for a while now :P +1

Answer (score 0):

`html_entity_decode()` works fine for me? **Edit:** This uses your PHP versions default charset which for me is UTF-8. Your default charset may not support `&mdash;`

Note that it returns the string and does not edit the string itself so try:

```
$name = html_entity_decode($name);
echo $name;
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? If you look into the source of the page, where you `echo $name`, you will get `&mdash;`, not `—`

Comment: I've run `echo html_entity_decode("Mount Kimbie &mdash; Carbonated.");` on my server and I get `Mount Kimbie — Carbonated.` in my page source.

Comment: viewing the source will display the source, not the rendered output, so of course you'll see &mdash; if you view source